# Slider Loads each slide before rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If you look at my URL below, and on a connection that may not be really speedy. You'd notice the slider at the top, loads each individual slide in a vertical list (Taking about 1000px space) before snapping into the way it's supposed to render - which is like a standard slider; displaying and sliding one slide at a time.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to allow my slider to load correctly?

Live site at >> http://tinyurl.com/cz6sawg

--- Thanks for any pointers, I'm thinking I need to find a script that allows the slides to be hidden until the slider / page is fully loaded before presenting them.

***Relevant jQuery:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#photo-rotator").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 6000);
});

</script>
```

***Relevant Mark-Up:***

```
<!-- Top of Page Slider FRAGILE -->

<div style="min-height: 280px;">

<div id="photo-rotator" style="">
<?php $slide_id=1; ?>
<?php
 $featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
 $featuredPosts->query("showposts=3");
 while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post();
 ?>

    <div id="slide-<?php echo $slide_id; $slide_id++;?>">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="post-image">
         <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'rotator-post-image' ); ?>
         <span class="title" style="font-style:italic; color:#999;"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
     </a>
     </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?><!--/close loop-->

    <ul id="slide-nav">
        <?php $nav_id=1; ?>
        <?php while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide-<?php echo $nav_id; ?>">
                    <span class="thumbnail" style="display:none;">
                    </span>
                    <p style="color:#F93; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: 18px;"><? the_title(); $nav_id++;?></p>

                    <div style="">

                    <!--<?php the_excerpt(); ?>-->

                    <?php if($text= get_post_meta($post->ID, "slidetext", true)) { ?>
                         <div class="">

                         <p style="font-weight: normal; color: #333; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><?php echo $text; ?></p> 

                         </div>
                        <?php } //else { print"<div>"; } ?>  

                    </div>   

                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?><!--/close loop-->
        </ul>
        </div>

</div>        

<!-- End Top page Slider FRAGILE -->
```

Comment: what does your jquery look like.   Are you calling the sliders after the page has loaded?

Comment: Just added the relevant jQuery above. I think that means on / with page load, right?

Comment: You need to add the relevant HTML as well or just jsFiddle it.

Comment: Since this has nothing to do with PHP, why are you showing it instead of the actual HTML output?

Comment: It's integrated into my Wordpress Theme / Site ~

Comment: I didn't think PHP could create this issue so didn't tag it. Do you think it's a possibility? ~~

Comment: it sounds like you are just concerned with the page rendering and if  so then the easy fix is through css hide the div then in the jquery which runs when the doc is ready, set the div back to visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit messy, and the question does not help, but in relation to the part of your question where it reads:

> *ou'd notice the slider at the top, loads each individual slide in a vertical list (Taking about 1000px space) before snapping into the way it's supposed to render*

You can **wrap the entire slider** content with a div and give `overflow:hidden;` to prevent the height of +/-1000px  on the page load:

**CSS**

```
#photo-rotatorWrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="photo-rotatorWrapper">
  <div id="photo-rotator">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**
You may need to set other `CSS` declarations for that wrapper in order to stay positioned correctly within your current HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks, Yes - this is what I've been trying as a solution as well. I've tried adding a wrapper around all of the mark-up, I've tried, using the div containers I already have coded and I've tried wrapping a div defining height and width with overflow hidden around my PHP include for the slider - and it pushes the slider way below and behind my page content and I haven't found a solution to keep it rendering in the normal place.

Comment: I've managed to use this concept and margin the slider where it's supposed to be. Though, it still loads oddly ~ this'll have to be the solution as I have no more time to pursue. Muchas Gracias.